# “Read permission” level does not allow users to see the global navigation i

Tags: navigation

If I give the "read" permission to users, the global navigation is not available in the webpage. If I give the "contribute" permission to the users, the global navigation is available, however the users can make the changes which I don't want them to do it. Any advice? Thanks

Comment: I am not using Medata navigation though. I am just using Global navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that on the navigation tab of the term, you select Simple link or Header. This will fix the issue.

[image]

[“Read permission” level will not allow users to see the metadata navigation tree](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/70124/read-permission-level-will-not-allow-users-to-see-the-metadata-navigation-tree)

[Metadata Navigation and Filtering showed up for one time only](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/69214/metadata-navigation-and-filtering-showed-up-for-one-time-only)